# How can a human expand their lifespan in Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e

Is there a way for a human character to increase their life span by any significant amount?

I want to expand his lifespan because I want him to eventually raise a dragon, but I know that's way outside of a human's or even elf's lifetime. Fluff-wise, the human is also draconic, as in he has dragon blood, though I'm not planning yet on taking any bloodline stuff for this.

We're playing Pathfinder, though D&D 3.5e material is allowed. Preferably he should remain himself and human. (This includes not becoming an evil lich.)

Also, since this will change answers by A LOT. I am going to be the host of the group. Which means I have GM duty since I'm the only one of us who's read dnd/pathfinder books.

Sources allowed as I know currently for sure

Pathfinder: Core rulebook, ultimate combat, ultimate magic, ultimate equipment, advanced class guide.

3.5: complete arcane. Races of Eberron*. complete warrior. Complete Arcane. Complete mage. PHB 2. Draconomicon. Races of the dragon.

Also pertaining to him he's most likely going to be a magus

Comment: Related: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/13244/how-can-i-attain-eternal-youth-through-alchemy

Comment: Potential duplicate: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/37094/760

Comment: Please don't answer in comments.

Comment: What level and control of classes is presumed here? What resources are, in general, available to this character?

Comment: DM PC with dragon screams "I'm trying to outdo my players". You really should be focusing on making an interesting world for your players, not trying to make outlandish characters.

Answer (score 6):

Hire someone to cast [reincarnate](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/reincarnate) on you every few years.

Upsides:

> The magic of the spell creates an entirely new young adult body for the soul to inhabit from the natural elements at hand

Downsides:

> If the subject is 1st level, it takes 2 points of Constitution drain instead

Happily, [restoration](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/restoration) will fix you *right up.* And, presuming you have enough money (which you do, being a GMPC with a dragon), strategic self-murders will rotate you back up to human before you know it.

With that out of the way, what you're proposing is stupid. You're not only going to be a GMPC, but you're going to be a GMPC *with a dragon.* Don't. Do. This. Focus on running a small game with your friends. Run them through a dungeon crawl, be liberal with healing potions. Then, run *another* mini-campaign. Then, don't make a GMPC. Don't make a [bazooka which carries its own bazooka](http://www.shamusyoung.com/twentysidedtale/?p=665).

Just focus all of your efforts on running the best game you can, for that will be more than difficult. Keep the scope low, iterate often, don't *plan* hugely elaborate things before playing. Just plan the next session.

Comment: I was not making a "bazooka which carries a bazooka" I simply liked the idea of a destined man who raises a dragon like that woman from game of thrones. Secondly: Even so my character won't be overpowered, I'm following all of the normal build rules for making a PC

Comment: also. I'm not planning hugely elaborate things for the campaign. I'm just putting a few plot points in. I do plan to keep sessions simple

Comment: What Brian means is that you are making a character that is "way cooler than anything your PCs will ever get". You're going to be running around with a dragon, at which point... why are the other players even there? Your dragon can just solve any problem. They're no longer the main part of the story, the GMPC with dragon is, they're just there to tag along and make him feel good.

Answer (score 3):

Briliant gameologists has a fairly [informative handbook](http://brilliantgameologists.com/boards/index.php?topic=5996) in becoming immortal for D&D 3.5e. Since you are the DM and willing to allow 3.5 material, you should be able to find something on it.

Answer (score 1):

In Pathfinder If the character is a Wizard or has access to the wizard [arcane discoveries](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-discoveries/arcane-discoveries-paizo) there is one available at level 20:

[Immortality](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-discoveries/arcane-discoveries-paizo/immortality)

> Benefit: You discover a cure for aging, and from this point forward
>   you take no penalty to your physical ability scores from advanced age.
>   If you are already taking such penalties, they are removed at this
>   time. This is an extraordinary ability.

Comment: You still die from aging I think. You just don't take penalties.